# Double Navigation Bar when I set translucent to NO

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uinavigationbar, navbar

When i set this code in viewDidLoad:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
```

and run the project in xcode, it creates other nav bar above of my main nav bar.

Anyone know what is it?

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                                                  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
    self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

The code above  set the nav bar from translucent to solid without hide or create an other nav bar.